# Visualizing Fluentd logs

Tags: open-source, visualization, fluentd, log-analysis

We have open source tech stack in our firm. We use fluentd as log collector. How can I visualize my fluentd logs? Which are good open source tools for log analysis and visualization. I have researched many but none seems to fit in. I am not interested in free trial versions of enterprise offerings. I want something under open source license. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of visualisation you want have?

Comment: Visualizations that can tell: 1) How many error logs I am getting. 2)Their corresponding error messages if I can expand that. 3) Which component is giving me maximum error messages and its root cause that we are sending in the logs etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you could use:

- Fluentd + ElasticSearch + Kibana
- Fluentd + Prometheus

Fluentd has plugin for both ElasticSearch and Prometheus (https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/monitoring-prometheus)

Comment: I cant use ElasticSearch as it has cost associated with it in terms of RAM. Instead I am trying the second option here.

Comment: Just to add: I integrated grafana also with the second option and It is working awesome. Thanks.